# How to get updated output using raw sql builder in gorm

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sql-update, go-gorm

**I'm trying to get my updated post in to a struct in the below function**

```
    func UpdatePost(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Param("id")

    var body struct {
        Title    string
        PostText string
        Img string
    }
    c.Bind(&body)

    var post models.Post

    initializers.DB.Raw("UPDATE posts SET title = ?, post_text = ?, img = ? WHERE id = ?", body.Title, body.PostText, body.Img, id).Scan(&post)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "post": post,
    })
}
```

My Post is being successfully updated in DB but
**even after using Scan(), my struct looks like this**

```
"post": {
    "ID": 0,
    "title": "",
    "postText": "",
    "img": "",
    "userName": "",
    "likedBy": null,
    "createdBy": 0,
}
```

What's the way to go here?

Comment: Add returning * after where id = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Missed RETURNING * after WHERE id = ? like @rahmat commented. Leaving this here for anyone who's trying to find the correct syntax for gorm raw SQL builder in future